# Adiabatic Exponent for an adiabatic process

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, adiabatic

Suppose we have some thermodynamic system, not necessarily a classical ideal gas, where
$$EV^{\gamma -1} = f(S,N)$$
Then for a process with constant $S, N,$ we have that
$$EV^{\gamma -1} = \rm const.$$
Now
$$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}\right)_{S,N} = -P=(1-\gamma)f(S,N)V^{-1}V^{1-\gamma}$$
$$PV=(\gamma -1)E$$
So
$$PV+E=\gamma E$$
and for a process with constant $S, N,$ we have that
$$PV^{\gamma} = \rm const.$$

**Question:**
Can it be shown that this $\gamma$ is the adiabatic exponent, where the adiabatic exponent is defined by
$$\gamma_{a} = \frac{C_P}{C_V}?$$
(This is not a homework question, so I do not know the right answer).

**Attempt:**
I do not think so.
$$\gamma_a=\frac{C_P}{C_V}
=\frac{\left(\frac{\partial(E+PV)}{\partial T}\right)_{P,N}}{
\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}} = \gamma  \cdot \frac{\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T}\right)_{P,N}}{\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}}$$
Now
$$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T}\right)_{P,N} = \left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N} + \left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}\right)_{T,N}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{P,N}$$
In other words, for
$\gamma_{a}=\gamma,$ we need to show that $E=E(N,V,T)$ is only actually only a function of $N, T,$ so that
$$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}\right)_{T,N} =0$$
This doesn't seem doable...
$$EV^{\gamma -1} = f(S,N) $$
$$E=f(S,N) V^{1-\gamma}$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}=T=\left(\frac{\partial f(S,N)}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N} V^{1-\gamma}$$
$$TV^{\gamma -1}=\left(\frac{\partial f(S,N)}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}$$
$$S=g(N,TV^{\gamma -1})$$
where $g$ is some function
$$\to E = h(N,TV^{\gamma -1})V^{1-\gamma}$$
where $h$ is some function. $E$ needs to be extensive, but this doesn't seem to be enough. For example,
$$E=N\tilde{h}\left(T\left(\frac{V}{N}\right)^{\gamma -1}\right) \left(\frac{V}{N}\right)^{1-\gamma}$$
where $\tilde{h}$ is some function of $T\left(\frac{V}{N}\right)^{\gamma -1}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just write your internal energy $E$ as $U$ and enthalpy $H = U+pV$. To simplify things (less variables) I'll only consider molar quantities and assume extensivity, which gets rid of $N$. The equation of state thus reads:
$$
U = V^{1-\gamma}f(S)
$$
Let's calculate $\gamma_a = \frac{C_p}{C_V}$. First off:
$$
C_V = \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}_V \\
= T\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_V \\
C_p = \frac{\partial H}{\partial T}_p \\
= T\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p
$$

so let us convert these partial derivatives into partial derivatives of our basis variables $S,V$:
$$
dS = \frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_VdT+\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}_TdV \\
\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_V = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\right)^{-1} \\
\left(1-\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}\right)dS= \frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_pdT+\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T\frac{\partial p}{\partial V} dV \\
\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\frac{\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}}{\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}}\right)^{-1}
$$

so:

$$
\gamma_a = \left(1-\frac{\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}}{\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}}\frac{\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}}{\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}}\right)^{-1} \\
= \left(1-\frac{\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial S\partial V}^2}{\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial S^2}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial V^2}}\right)^{-1} \\
=\left(1-\frac{((1-\gamma)V^{-\gamma}f')^2}{V^{1-\gamma}f''(1-\gamma)(-\gamma)V^{-1-\gamma}f}\right)^{-1} \\
=\left(1+(\gamma^{-1}-1)\frac{f'^2}{f''f}\right)^{-1} \\
$$

so for a general $f$, $\gamma_a\neq \gamma$. Actually, they are equal iff:
$$
f''f = (f')^2 \\
f = Ae^{BS}
$$
with $A,B$ two constants. Note that this is true in particular for ideal gases which probably motivated your question in the first place.

Hope this helps.

**Answer to comment**

I’ll detail the calculations of $\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p$:
\begin{align}
dS &= \frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p dT+ \frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T dp \\
&= \frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p dT+ \frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial S} dS + \frac{\partial p}{\partial V} dV \right)\\
dT &= \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p\right)^{-1} \left(1-\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}\right)dS -\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p\right)^{-1} \frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T\frac{\partial p}{\partial V} dV \\
dT &= \frac{\partial T}{\partial S} dS + \frac{\partial T}{\partial V} dV
\end{align}
By identifying the factors in front of the $dS,dV$ I obtain have a system of equations with two unknowns: $\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p, \frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T $:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial T}{\partial S} &= \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p\right)^{-1} \left(1-\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}\right) \tag{1} \\
\frac{\partial T}{\partial V} &= -\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p\right)^{-1} \frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T\frac{\partial p}{\partial V} \tag{2}
\end{align}

which I solve by doing:
$$
(1)-\frac{\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}}{\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}}(2)
$$

and recover the advertised formula:
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial S}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\frac{\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}}{\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}}\right)^{-1}
$$

Comment: I checked the math again, and it looks correct, no missing factor. I'm just expressing $dS$ with respect to $dp,dT$, then expanding $dp$ with respect to $dS,dV$ and finally regrouping. Could you elaborate please? How would it affect  the final for result for $\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p$?

Comment: Thank you, I realized how you did that step, and I believe it is correct. The step after it though, seems incorrect. $dS= \left(1-\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}\right)^{-1}\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_pdT+...$
Implying
$\left(1-\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}\right)^{-1}\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p = \frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_V$
So
$\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_p = \left(1-\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}_T\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}\right)\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}_V$. At this point, I am not sure how to proceed.